# MUI Nav Tab with NextJS router - adding icon results in undefined TypeError

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've implemented `NavTabs` similar to the implementation found [here](https://mui.com/components/tabs/#nav-tabs), but using `next/router`.

**Problem:** The app crashes if you add an `icon` to any `Tab`.

[Live Codesandbox reproduction](https://codesandbox.io/s/next-js-forked-6oxtmo?file=/pages/index.js)

In the Codesandbox, clicking either tab will cause the error. If you then remove the `icon` property from both `Tab` components, it will work without issue.

The full code and MUI documentation can be found below.

[image]

**Additional detail and logging errors:**

If you were to use no label and only an icon, like this:

```
import HomeIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Home'
<LinkTab href="/drafts" icon = {<HomeIcon />} />
```

Then a click can result in a `TypeError` thrown at `router.push(e.target.href)`. The same error occurs if you use all three of `label`, `icon`, and `aria-label`.

In the `handleTabChange` method, I logged the `event` and found what's changing.

The event from a successful click on a `LinkTab` with no `icon`:

```
SyntheticBaseEvent {_reactName: 'onClick', _targetInst: null, type: 'click', nativeEvent: 
PointerEvent, target: a.MuiButtonBase-root.MuiTab-root.MuiTab-textColorPrimary.css-knz1ty- 
MuiButtonBase-root-MuiTab-root, …}
```

The event from an unsuccessful click on a `LinkTab` with an `icon`:

```
SyntheticBaseEvent {_reactName: 'onClick', _targetInst: null, type: 'click', nativeEvent: 
PointerEvent, target: path, …}
```

It seems that the target changes to `path` sometimes, and as far as I can tell this only happens when an icon is present in the `LinkTab`.

Any ideas how I can get around this?

**Alternative attempt #1:**

The below implementation updates the state of the `Tabs` without crashing, but it won't actually navigate to a new page. If you try to add `onClick` to the individual `Tab` components, then the `Tabs` state won't update as expected.

```
<Tabs value = {value} onChange = {(e, v) => handleChange(e, v)} aria-label = 'nav'>
  <Tab icon = {<HomeIcon />} aria-label = 'home' value = {pages[0]} to = {pages[0]} component = {Link} />
  <Tab icon = {<AboutIcon />} aria-label = 'about' value = {pages[1]} to = {pages[1]} component = {Link} />
</Tabs>
```

**Alternative attempt #2:**

The below implementation also results in the same `TypeError`:

```
import TabContext from '@mui/lab/TabContext'
import TabList from '@mui/lab/TabList'

<TabContext value = {value}>
  <TabList value = {value} onChange = {(e, v) => handleChange(e, v)} centered aria-label = 'nav'>
    <LinkTab icon = {<HomeIcon />} href = {pages[0]} aria-label = 'home' />
    <LinkTab icon = {<InfoIcon />} href = {pages[1]} aria-label = 'about' />
  </TabList>
</TabContext>
```

**Error log**:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'auth')
    at Object.formatUrl (format-url.js?7b53:32:11)
    at Object.formatWithValidation (utils.js?e7ff:109:28)
    at resolveHref (router.js?8684:190:69)
    at prepareUrlAs (router.js?8684:247:38)
    at Router.push (router.js?8684:532:26)
    at Object.instance.<computed> [as push] (router.js?31fc:150:20)
    at handleTabChange (NavTabs.js?141c:61:12)
    at onClick (NavTabs.js?141c:69:25)
    at handleClick (Tab.js?4f19:161:1)
    ...
```

**Full code (also found on Codesandbox)**:

`index.js`:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useState } from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Tabs from "@mui/material/Tabs";
import Tab from "@mui/material/Tab";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import HomeIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Home";
import InfoIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Info";

const StyledTab = styled(Tab)(({ theme }) => ({
  color: theme.palette.text.primary,
  "&:hover": { color: theme.palette.primary.main }
}));

const LinkTab = (props) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleTabChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    e.preventDefault();
    router.push(e.target.href);
  };

  return (
    <StyledTab
      component="a"
      disableFocusRipple
      disableRipple
      onClick={(e) => handleTabChange(e)}
      {...props}
    />
  );
};

export const NavTabs = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const pages = ["/", "/about"];
  const [value, setValue] = useState(pages.indexOf(router.route));

  const handleChange = (e, v) => {
    setValue(v);
  };

  return (
    <Box>
      <Tabs value={value} onChange={(e, v) => handleChange(e, v)} centered>
        <LinkTab
          label="Home"
          href={pages[0]}
          icon={<HomeIcon />}
          aria-label="home"
        />
        <LinkTab
          label="About"
          href={pages[1]}
          icon={<InfoIcon />}
          aria-label="about"
        />
      </Tabs>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default () => (
  <div>
    <NavTabs />
  </div>
);
```

`about.js`:

```
import NavTabs from "./index";

export default () => (
  <div>
    <NavTabs />
  </div>
);
```

**MUI documentation:**

https://mui.com/components/tabs/#api

https://mui.com/components/tabs/#nav-tabs

https://mui.com/components/tabs/#icon-tabs

https://mui.com/components/tabs/#experimental-api

https://mui.com/components/tabs/#third-party-routing-library

https://mui.com/guides/routing/#tabs

https://mui.com/guides/routing/#next-js

Comment: As per the docs to use the icon with Tab you don't need to pass `label` but you do need to pass `aria-label` or you need to create your own link component as per the docs check out https://mui.com/components/tabs/#third-party-routing-library

Comment: @AliHussnain I've tried something like that but haven't been able to get it working. If you have a working example, please post it as an answer

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue could be. Your code looks to be valid as per the documentation. It might be an issue with the package itself. I'll try a little bit more experimentation.